# PhpStorm 2017.1 shows ' undefined namespace Phalcon'

Tags: ide, phpstorm, phalcon, phpstorm-2017.1, php-ide

In [PhpStorm 2017.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/) version, I get the error - **"undefined namespace Phalcon. Referenced namespace is not found".**  So I tried to include the Phalcon [devtools](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools). I included them and the 'External Liabraries' of the project Explorer found the name - Phalcon. Even I can load the project url and get output in browser. But the message still appears.

[image]

Another screenshot goes below to show the folder i selected in the include path. notice that under 'ide->Phpstorm', i do not see  any other file or directory.

[image]

Other answers in SO use a back version of Phalcon devtools.

How can i remove the message and get PhpStorm handle Phalcon smartly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Phalcon 3.1 stubs are available in separated repository - https://github.com/phalcon/ide-stubs

Comment: And it worked ! BTW where can I find this information in Phalcon documentation or Phpstorm doc or elsewhere ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed If it is worked, could you accept answer?

Comment: I think it was mentioned in some blog post https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/phalcon-ide-stubs-repository

Comment: @Juri, How to install the IDE stub globally i.e. for all the  projects? The above method applies for  a single project .

Comment: Well, add it to composer.json and composer install. It will be there. Also you can edit default settings and in new projects it will be there. Idk about current existing ones.

Comment: If anyone wants to make a PhpStorm plugin out of these stubs please follow the instruction https://github.com/artspb/phpstorm-library-plugin It's pretty simple and should not take much time to build and maintain.

Comment: phpstorm plugin already exists, please search in repository: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9536-phalcon-auto-complete

even better: it's open-sourced with GPL license :) so please contribute.